# spring integration - multiple gateway

Tags: spring, spring-integration, gateway

In my project I would be having two inbound gateways with same input params but different response. Each gateway is called declared in a different xml. The problem is when I call gateway1 it goes to xml2 instead of xml1. 
How should we handle this. Have two gateways in the same interface

```
public interface MessageGateway {
    @Gateway(requestChannel="requestChannel1")
    @Payload("#args")
    public Response1 invoke(Bean bean) throws Exception;

    @Gateway(requestChannel="requestChannel2")
    @Payload("#args")
    public List<Response2> invoke2(Bean bean) throws Exception;

}
```

In xml1

```
<int:gateway id="invoke" default-request-channel="requestChannel1" default-reply-channel="finalResult"
                 service-interface="<class name>" error-channel="errorChannel" default-reply-timeout="6000"/>
    <int:channel id="errorChannel"/>
```

In xml2

```
<int:gateway id="invoke1" default-request-channel="requestChannel2" default-reply-channel="finalResult"
                     service-interface="<class name>" error-channel="errorChannel" default-reply-timeout="6000"/>
        <int:channel id="errorChannel"/>
```

I call the gateway from another system. SO I autowire the gateway interface and call the methods.

As per Gary's comment adding the autowiring

```
@Autowired
private MessageGateway gateway;
//calling
gateway.invoke(bean);
```

Comment: Show your autowiring for both gateways.

Comment: It's probably better to put the methods in different interfaces to avoid confusion. With this configuration, both gateways have 2 methods.

Comment: That autowiring should fail - you have 2 beans `invoke` and `invoke1`. Spring doesn't know how to choose which one for the auto wiring. You either need just one `<gateway/>` or you should put the methods on separate interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

Look. you don't need two `<gateway>` definitions for the same interface.

If you worry about `requestChannel` you can use that property on the `@Gateway` annotation or `<method>` sub-element of the `<gateway>`.

In case of two `<gateway>`s it looks like the second one wins and we have proxy only for that part of configuration.

Comment: Thanks Artem for the explanation. But, how do I make sure that I call the correct gateway and related xml.

Comment: Not sure in your question. Just make a one `<gateway>` and specify particular `request-channel`s for each `@Gateway` methods.

Answer (score 0):

A solution is to declare a method sub element.  See also the loadBrokerGateway here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/2.0.0.RC1/reference/html/gateway.html.

So XML1

```
<int:gateway id="invoke" default-request-channel="requestChannel1" default-reply-channel="finalResult" service-interface="<class name>" error-channel="errorChannel" default-reply-timeout="6000">
    <int:method name="invoke" request-channel="requestChannel1" />
</int:gateway>
<int:channel id="errorChannel"/>
```

And XML2

```
<int:gateway id="invoke1" default-request-channel="requestChannel2" default-reply-channel="finalResult" service-interface="<class name>" error-channel="errorChannel" default-reply-timeout="6000">
    <int:method name="invoke" request-channel="requestChannel2" />
</int:gateway>
<int:channel id="errorChannel"/>
```